# mongo aggregate group and find one

Tags: mongodb

I have collections in mongodb: which stores as:

```
{"tag":"count1","value":100,"ts":1544423706} {"tag":"count2","value":1002,"ts":1544423706} {"tag":"count1","value":101,"ts":1544423806} {"tag":"count2","value":1003,"ts":1544423806} {"tag":"count1","value":102,"ts":1544423906} {"tag":"count2","value":1004,"ts":1544423906}
```

so my problem is how can I get the result out of "tag" is count1 , "ts" is larger than 1544423800's first item. As I describled: I want to find the result as:

```
{"tag":"count1","value":101,"ts":1544423806} {"tag":"count2","value":1003,"ts":1544423806}
```

do I need use aggregate to group the tag and then get the first item which larger than given "ts", I am new to aggregate function in MongoDB.

```
  db.index.aggregate([{"$match": {"tag": {"$in":["count1","count2"]},"ts": {"$gt":1544423800}}
                        },
            {"$group": {"_id": "$tag",
                        "tags": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}}
                        },
        ])
```

which the result is not one item for each tag so I want to limit one item , what am I have to do

thank you  I have solve this by :

```
db.index.aggregate(

[
            {"$match": {"tag": {"$in":["count1","count2"]},
                                             "ts": {"$gt":1545730000}}
                        },
            {"$group": {"_id": "$tag",
                        "value": {"$first": "$value"}
                                             }
                        },

        ]

)
```

Comment: Normal find query should work, you just have to do greater than query for ts field.

Comment: @Sikorski find greater query where find all the count1 and count2 greater than ts but I only want to find one